# JavaScript: loop through DOM tree and replace text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use JavaScript to loop through the DOM tree of a webpage and replace every instance of the word 'hipster' with a different word UNLESS it is part of a link or image src. Example, if 'hipster' appears in a paragraph, it should be replaced.

But if it's in the `src=""` url for an image, that **should not** be replaced because if it replaces that word in a url, the url obviously breaks.

I've been having a really hard time implementing this. Here's one thing I tried:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
     if(i.nodeType == 3){
        i.html().replace(/hipster/gi, 'James Montour');
     }
     else{
       //do nothing for now
     }
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to check your question? It doesn't make sense. "So if 'hipster' appears in a paragraph, for example, it should be replaced. But if it's in the src url for an image, that should be replaced." Didn't you mean "shouldn't" in one of your cases?

Comment: Same again, I'm afraid. Now your 1st & 2nd paras say the opposite of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re close, but:

- `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` will never return text nodes; it gets elements only (and comment nodes in old versions of IE)
- Text nodes don’t have an `html()` method
- `replace` doesn’t modify strings in place

With that in mind, you can get every child of every element, check their types, read their `nodeValue`s, and, if appropriate, replace the entire node:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace(/hipster/gi, 'James Montour');

            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try it out on this page!

Comment: Worked like a charm! I had never worked with nodeType before so got kind of lost there.

Answer (score -1):

To use variables instead of 'hipster' replace:

```
var replacedText = text.replace(/hipster/gi, 'James Montour');
```

with these lines:

```
var needle = 'hipster';
var replacement = 'James Montour';
var regex = new RegExp(needle, "gi");
var replacedText = text.replace(regex, replacement);
```